# Convert into Beta Function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Could somebody show me how to convert $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ { \bigg [ \left( 1-{ x }^{ 1/17} \right) }^{ 23 } } +{ \left( 1-{ x }^{ 1/23 } \right) }^{ 17 } \bigg ] dx$$ into the Beta Function? I could recognize the similarity of the Integrand and the limits of Integration to those of the Beta Function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may write, using the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function),
$$\begin{align}
\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \left( 1-{ x }^{ 1/17} \right)^{23 } dx&=17\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } { \left( 1-u \right) }^{23}u^{16} du \qquad (u=x^{1/17},\,dx=17u^{16}du)\\\\
&=17\:B(24,17)\\\\
&=17\:\frac{\Gamma(24)\Gamma(17)}{\Gamma(24+17)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{88732378800}.
\end{align}
$$ Similarly, you get
$$\begin{align}
\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } \left( 1-{ x }^{ 1/23} \right)^{17} dx&=23\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 } { \left( 1-u \right) }^{17}u^{22} du \qquad (u=x^{1/23},\,dx=23u^{22}du)\\\\
&=23\:B(18,23)\\\\
&=23\:\frac{\Gamma(18)\Gamma(23)}{\Gamma(18+23)}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{88732378800}.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Notice that both “halves” of your integral represent the area of the same [geometric shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse), given by the implicit equation $x^a+y^b=1$, where $a=\dfrac1{17}$ and $b=\dfrac1{23}$. :-$)$